# FileReader.readAsDataURL not working for some file types in IE10

Tags: javascript, filereader

```
$('#file').on('change', function (e) {
    if (FileReader) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.onloadend = function (x) {
            var other = x.target.result;
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {

        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
});
```

This is an input of type="file".  This works when selecting several file types.  But, for some file types e.target.result (including tiff) always comes back null.

```
e.target.result = null or empty (for some file types)
e.target.error = null.  
e.target.readyState = 2.
e.total is always a large positive number.
```

The result of onloadend is the same as onload and onerror never gets hit.

Please note that this seems to be an IE10 issue.  It works fine in IE11, Chrome, and FireFox.  My OS is Server 2012.

Comment: Side note: `if (FileReader) {` isn't a good way to test for the File API, it will throw an exception if it's not present. You may have meant `if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {`, which won't.

Comment: My guess is you're hitting the size limit for `data:` URIs on IE.

Comment: Yup.  I tried a smaller tiff and it works in IE10.  I get a result.  Is there any way to increase the limit?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Why do you need it as a `data:` URI, as opposed to actual data?

Comment: Trying to match the contract on an asmx service I am consuming.  It wants to receive the data as a byte[].
We have an existing Silverlight app that uses the service and we wanted to reuse it.  Apparently, the fact that Silverlight is calling the service in the existing app it doesn't run into any file size issues.